# Текст парсинг в python

Tags: python, parse

```
import re

a = 'description:"Trimble X7 –  современный компактный лазерный сканер для решения широкого круга задач в сфере гражданского и промышленного строительства, информационного моделирования по облакам точек (scan – to  - BIM), обмера помещений, сьемки промышленных и инфраструктурных объектов"'

opisanie = re.findall(r'description:"*"', a.text)            
print(opisanie)
```

Здравствуйте, я ищу текст в переменной a, у меня вместо текста выходит ['description:"']
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем причина?

Comment: Причина в том, что ты не ознакомился с тем, что означают спецсимволы в регулярных выражениях, да и, похоже, вообще не знаешь, как они работают.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внимательнее надо. `"*"` - это значит `"` 0 или более раз, затем ещё кавычка. Естественно, что под этот шаблон подходит то, что у вас выводится. Нужно сделать:

- либо `".*"` - т.е. `"`, затем произвольные символы 0 или более раз, затем `"`
- либо `"[^"]*"` - т.е. `"`, затем НЕ `"` 0 или более раз, и затем опять `"`